# Are the Dyson formulae of time evolution perturbative?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, hamiltonian, perturbation-theory, time-evolution

In many books, e.g., Sakurai's modern quantum mechanics revised edition Chap 2 p73 & Chap 5 p 326 (though he said Chap 2 similar to Chap 5 from what I understood), Peskin and Schroeder's introduction to QFT 4.2 `Perturbation Expansion of Correlation Functions`, p 88, Eq. (4.22), it is claimed the [Dyson series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dyson_series) is perturbative, due to the iterative proof, from what I understood.

In P&S' (4.22), it is given
$$
U(t,t_0) = 1 + (-i) \int_{t_0}^t dt_1 H_I (t) + \frac{ (-i)^2}{2!}  \int_{t_0}^t dt_1  dt_2 T\{ H_I (t_1 ) H_I (t_2 ) \}  + \cdots (1)
 \equiv T \{ \exp[ -i \int_{t_0}^{t} dt' H_I(t') ] \}, (2)
$$
(I added equation labels (1) and (2))

But, in the recent aspects from the Trotter-Suzuki formula,
e.g., https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/q/17032/
and https://arxiv.org/abs/1805.11568, Eq. (1),
$$ U(T) := \mathcal{T} \exp \left[ - \dfrac{i}{\hbar} \int_0^T H(t) \, dt \right]  (3) $$
seems in the arXiv paper above, (3) is exact without refer to perturbation context. "Exact" means pluging in Eq. (3) to the time-dependent Schroedinger equation will in principle lead to the exact solution of the  time-dependent Schroedinger equation, here $ i \hbar \partial t \psi = H \psi$, not involving mathematical subtleties such as weak solution.

Here are my questions:

1. What is the role of perturbation in this context, regarding non-perturbative aspect? The non-perturbative means here the interaction Hamiltonian is very large, the very does not carry strict mathematical sense yet. The forms of interaction Hamiltonian are e.g., textbook examples in time-dependent sections, external fields in quantum mechanics/QCD etc
2. Regarding 1, does it mean in any given Hamiltonian including the interactions, despite how large the interaction, as long as we compute all series (in-principle), we will get the exact solution in the time-dependent Schrödinger picture?
3. Is there any subtle difference in the exponential form (2) and the infinity series summation (1)? P&S used $\equiv$, when the interaction Hamiltonian is very large, are equations (1) - (3) still all hold?

Namely, is the Dyson series still exact in non-perturbative region?

In Spectral Theory and Quantum Mechanics by Moretti, proposition 9.27, the sufficient condition includes $||V_t|| \leq C$, seems about bounded operator to me. But I am not sure if that hold for polynomial field operators in field theories or multiple expansion in QM, e.g., $x$ from the dipole approximation, ref http://sporadic.stanford.edu/conformal/lecture1.pdf, page 22,
"$\hat{q}_i^j$ and $\hat{p}_i^j$ are unbounded operators..."

Comment: Can you give detailed references (edition, chapter, pages)...?! Also, what exactly do you want to know? When eq. $(1)$ holds?

Comment: If all $H(t)$ are bounded (e.g. when you work with a finite-dimensional Hilbert space) and some more elaborated smaller remarks, it holds true. In more general cases, it is again much more complicated. See e.g. the book on spectral theory in QM by V. Moretti (who is a user here actually) and by Blank et. al on Hilbert spaces operators in quantum physics.

Comment: I have given two references. It is not clear what you mean with "exact"--mathematically well-defined or in a more physical sense exact? For the latter, define what you mean with "non-perturbative regime". Yes, the equation is valid (ignoring mathematical things) for situations where you don't apply perturbation theory and so on. It is just a way to write the time-evolution operator.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, the formula (1) that you wrote is exact as an infinite series. However, it is generally not possible to *solve* for the operator form of $U(T)$, unless, e.g., $H(t)$ is particularly simple or $[H(t),H(t')]=0$ for all $t,t' \in [0,T]$. The Dyson series can be thought of as a perturbative expansion, but it is exact when all terms are retained, as with any perturbative series. In practice, we generally can't evaluate all terms.

As with any series expansion, there could potentially be issues related to convergence and "nonperturbative effects," but nothing comes to mind in this context. Taylor series may fail to converge to any value in some domain or at some points, or may converge to the wrong value. However, as far as I know, this would indicate a problem with the resulting unitary (i.e., that it is unphysical or something diverges).

Your expression (3) is simply the definition of the time evolution operator in generic closed quantum systems. But the time-ordering operator $\mathcal{T}$ is not defined above. The way we define $\cal T$ is by expanding the exponential. One way to define $\cal T$ and $U(T)$ is using the Lie-Suzuki-Trotter decomposition, which is based on the limit
$$ e^x = \lim_{N \to \infty} \left( 1 + \frac{x}{N} \right)^N ,$$
and the time-ordering operator $\cal T$ simply ensures that the time argument that appears in each of the $N \to \infty$ copies of $H(t_n)$ are chronologically ordered.

The other way to define $\cal T$ and $U(T)$ is through the Taylor expansion of $e^x$, which results in the Dyson series (1). The series is regarded as "perturbative" for the same reason as any perturbative expansion: We usually don't keep all terms. If you keep all terms, it's no longer perturbative. However, there are cases when the series fails to converge (or does not converge to the correct value), corresponding to nonperturbative effects.

I prefer the Trotter decomposition as a formal definition, and I think it is always safe / well defined. But the Dyson series leads to Feynman diagrams, which are handy. It's possible that the Dyson series could fail to converge / fail to converge to the correct value, in which case (3) would only be definable in terms of the Trotter decomposition. If neither works, then (3) is not valid as far as I know, because of how $\cal T$ is defined.

As for your enumerated questions:

1. The role of perturbation theory is that we usually truncate the Dyson series (1) and that it may not converge in all cases, as with any series. When the series is well defined and equal to (3) and expressed to all orders, it is exactly equal to (3).
2. It means if you kept terms of all order in (1), you'd get an exact solution of (3). Applying this to the initial state gives the exact time-evolved state. So, yes.
3. The expressions (2) and (3) should be equivalent, but may be expressed in different pictures (e.g., Schrödinger vs. interaction). The size of the interaction only matters when it comes to truncating the series (1). The Taylor series of $e^x$ is still valid for large argument, the things to worry about are more like the Taylor series for $\log x$ when $|x| > 1$ or the failure of the Taylor series for $e^{-1/x}$ about $x=0$. The Trotter version should always be safe, as far as I know.

The Dyson series is not exact (or even necessarily approximate) if the series itself fails to converge or doesn't converge to the right value, which is what "nonperturbative" means.

The reference you linked seems to be wrong about what a bounded operator is. It's not the magnitude of the operator $|V|$ that appears but the size $\| X \|$ of the image of the operator relative the codomain. However, a bounded operator has to have a bounded spectrum, so $|V_t| \leq C$ *does* mean that $V_t$ is bounded. Also note that the position and momentum operators are arbitrarily close to bounded linear operators in the sense of operator topology. So I could see the lack of boundedness of these operators not being fatal to the Dyson series being well defined, depending on the states to which the series is applied.

Comment: “ Like any perturbative series, the Dyson series is exact only if we evaluate all of the infinitely many terms.” but even we compute all terms, it will not necessarily be exact for non-perturbative region.

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out! I've added a comment after the sentence you quoted.

Comment: Why do you call it "perturbative series"? Is the series expression for $e^x$ "perturbative"?! Apart from (important) mathematical things, the equation is of course valid, as it is just a convenient way to re-write the time-evolution operator. I mean, this might be a matter of convention/terminology, but, as I said, and as far as I understand you also point out: the series itself is exact, any truncation is (in general) not.

Comment: @RandomUser What is "exact"?!

Comment: @TobiasFünke "exact" means using the given formula can in-principle lead to the exact solution of the equation (I don't distinguish mathematical subtitles such as weak solution). Perhaps the confusing point is, I thought $e^x = 1 + x + x^2 + \cdots $ both refer to the Dyson series. Could it be the exp form is exact in the previous sense, the series 1 + x + ... has convergence conditions? The non-perturbative means when the interaction term is sufficiently large. Let me update my question

Comment: @TobiasFünke Question updated

Comment: I updated the answer accordingly. As for the comment from @TobiasFünke I think this is convention. Because we generally truncate the Dyson series, like a perturbative expansion (which would also be exact if the full infinite series were retained). When I say "exact" I mean (1) and (3) mathematically equivalent, when (1) is not truncated. As RandomUser notes, series can have domains of convergence outside of which they fail to converge to the correct value or any value. Hopefully this was helpful.